# Python - Outlook Response (Accept, Reject, etc.) Date/Time

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am working on a project that involves pulling a lot of appointment/meeting data from Outlook from multiple people.  One piece of information that I am trying to find is the response for *each* attendee and, if possible, the date and time that the response happened.  For example, if Person X sends me a meeting request on 4/21/2015 12:31:00 PM and I accepted the meeting request at 4/21/2015 1:30:00 PM, how would I get the latter of those two times?  I have been browsing the Microsoft docs for this ([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem_properties.aspx)) but have had no luck so far.

Here is a quick summary in Python:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')

recipient = namespace.createRecipient('Other Person')
resolved = recipient.Resolve()
sharedCalendar = namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9)

appointments = sharedCalendar.Items

for i in range(0,1):
    print appointments[i]
    print appointments[i].start
    print appointments[i].end
    print appointments[i].organizer
    print appointments[i].location
    print appointments[i].duration

    for j in range(0,len(appointments[i].recipients)):
        print 'recip, status: ' + str(appointments[i].recipients[j]) + ', ' + str(appointments[i].recipients[j].TrackingStatusTime)
```

Comment: I don't know if this helps but if this is possible I would think it would be located somewhere around this site: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olresponsestatus.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AppointmentItem.ReplyTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869193.aspx) and [AppointmentItem.ResponseStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868658.aspx)

Comment: Would it be possible to get ReplyTime for each Recipient?  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, use Recipient.MeetingResponseStatus property. Note that it will be set only on the appointment in the organizer's calendar folder.

Comment: I believe getting 'ReplyTime' is not possible for MeetingResponseStatus (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olresponsestatus.aspx)).

Comment: It is possible - Recipient.TrackingStatusTime will return the time will the response was sent by the attendee.

Comment: Great.  Is there any caveat to Recipient.TrackingStatusTime?  When I get this field, I am retrieving nearly all '01/01/01 00:00:00' values.  I am referencing namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder() to get this data... is this possibly restricting what info I can see?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It will only be populated on the organizer's side - create a meeting, send it to another attendee, have that attendee accept it and send the response. You can see the property in OutlookSpy: select the appointment, click Item button, select Recipients property, clic kBrowse, go to the IEnumVariant tab, double click on the attendee.

Comment: I would need this to be all in Python.  It sounds like what I am asking for is not possible.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: Why is it not possible? What prevents you from looping through the MailItem.Recipients collection and for each Recipient object reading the MeetingResponseStatus and TrackingStatusTime properties?

Comment: I did loop through that but I was getting '01/01/01 00:00:00'.  You mentioned that it will only be populated on the organizer's side.  I have access to everyone's calendar... is there a way to get the organizer's calendar folder?

Comment: You can opens it using Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder, but you must be given an explicit permission to access it. At the very least (if GetSharedDefaultFolder cannot be used) you will be able to read the attendee status for the appointments that the current user organized.

Comment: I must be doing something incorrectly then.  I edited the code above to show the for loop I am using (at the end) to retrieve the TrackingStatusTime.  I am still getting all '01/01/01 00:00:00'.  I should have full permission to this individuals calendar.

Comment: Nevermind... I had a minor error in my code.  I figured it out.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

here is another way

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

for i, msg in enumerate(messages):
    
    print(msg.MessageClass) # use this in condition

    if msg.MessageClass=='IPM.Note':
        print('This a Meeting')

    elif msg.MessageClass =='IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request':
        print('This is a meeting Meeting')
    elif msg.MessageClass =='IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Pos':
        print('Accepted Response , POS = Positive')
    elif msg.MessageClass =='IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Tent':
        print('Accepted as Tentative ')
    elif msg.MessageClass == 'IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Neg':
        print('Declined Meeting , Neg = Negative')

    # Check only first 10 items, change the number as per requirement
    if i > 10:
        break
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/Concepts/Forms/item-types-and-message-classes

Comment: Hi, How can I print the meeting request start day?